# C++ - Dumping a function from memory on a file then running it on another process

Tags: c++, function, assembly, memory, stack

So I have this piece of code:

```
// This is supposed to be used in order to dump "DummyFunc" in a file. Using a simple fwrite() call once we get the data inside the function.
int DummyFunc(LPVOID, LPVOID)
{
    return 0;
}

DWORD GetFuncSize(LPVOID function)
{
    DWORD size = 1;
    while (*(DWORD*)(((DWORD)function) + size) != 0xC3)
        size++;
    return size;
}

void DumpFunction(LPVOID dest, DWORD size, LPVOID function)
{
    memcpy(dest, function, size);
}

typedef     int(__cdecl* FUNC_T)(LPVOID, LPVOID);
```

Then I do the following:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, "data.txt", "r");  // Where I actually write the function's dump.
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        LPVOID func = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 5000, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        fread_s(func, 5000, 0, 1, file);

        FUNC_T tt = (FUNC_T)func;  //FUNC_T is declared above.
        int retval = tt(NULL, NULL);

        cout << retval << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get an access violation (before using VirtualAlloc()) and after VirtualAlloc() now I get the following message and the access violation too:

> The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location.
>   After that I follow the Diassembly and I get here:

```
00382000  add         byte ptr [eax],al
```

^ The above address is where I get the access violation. Now my guess is that either I am doing something wrong retrieving the function data or the way I'm allocating the dumped function in memory is plain wrong. Perhaps the function uses sections of .data which are not allocated in the current process? Or is it just impossible to transfer a function from a process into another this way?
Basically I want to be able to transfer functions over sockets in another program running in a different machine.
I'm not that good at these so please excuse me for my actual ignorance =[

Comment: Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR). You cannot portably dump a function. Your approach is wrong, and you need to motivate your question (and explain the goal of your entire program). BTW a C++ function might not be compiled into a *contiguous* sequence of bytes.

Comment: You cannot inject code into another process that way.

Comment: I can honestly say that after 25 years of C++ hacking, I never at once found myself in a situation where I needed to "dump" function code to a file, read it back, and try to execute it. Whatever problem this is intended to fix, it won't work.

Comment: **Why do you want to do that?** Please edit your question to improve it by giving much more motivation and context.

Comment: You really don't want to use text mode file for binary data.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: that reply actually made me laugh tbh. In short words I want to be able to send a piece of data to another machine via sockets and along with the data the instructions on how to manipulate it (aka a function). I'm starting to think however that what I'm trying to do is plain stupid.

Comment: I started giggling when I saw `!= 0xC3` :P

Comment: @NikosC. that was the best that I could've think of lmao...

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it. Give the actual context, and explain what kind of program are you writing. I strongly suspect that your approach is not reasonable. BTW, did you consider switching to some free software system (e.g. Linux and its free software C++ compilers)? Are you allowed to change programming languages (your thing would be easier in Common Lisp)?

Comment: Please explain **what kind of program you are coding**. I'm sure that at some higher level, your problem could be approached otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, I want to be able to transfer functions over sockets in another program running in a different machine.

**This is impossible** (think of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), etc....).

<sup>(even if you happen to make something, it would be *very brittle* and sensitive to tiny changes, e.g. in the runtime, in the libraries used, in the compiler or operating system version or options, etc...; so don't even try)</sup>

What you might consider is: transferring some higher level representation of that function. It could be a function name, if you know it. It could be some [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (in whatever programming language is convenient for you) of the code of the function (and you need to consider closed values, etc; read about [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))). It could even be C++ source code.

For example, you might just share some C++ source code of [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), and transmit that C++ source code, and compile it on the destination machine into some plugin then [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) it.

Or you could embed some [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) (e.g. [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [Lua](http://lua.org/), ....) and/or some [JIT compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (e.g. [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), ...) in your application, and transmit closures. Even that is really hard.

You need to **redesign your entire program**.

<sup>(and sadly, you need to throw a lot of code)</sup>

Read also about [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) and about [homoiconic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

<sup>PS. It is sad that you did not motivate your question even more and explained your actual application and context. Your question looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).</sup>

Comment: Well can I just store all the functions in a DLL and simply send the DLL along with the data to work with. Then just use the DLL to get the functions?

Comment: Even that might not work. a DLL is compiled for a particular system and is not as portable as you want it to be.

Comment: @ElioDecolli If you're looking for a scripting language, which will allow you to send source code to another program and then run it, you can look into something like Lua (google for `c++ lua`), or [Chaiscript](http://chaiscript.com).

Comment: @NikosC. this might actually be a better approach. and Basile thanks for everything, and yeah what I was trying to do is exchange functions between two machines.

Comment: But **why** do you exchange code and functions between two machines? What kind of application are you trying to make? Your software design is probably wrong... If you told us about your application you could get more useful hints.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch well I want to make two or more machines work together. Basically like cryptocurrencies mining pools, but but instead of solving a global algorithm, a huge set of data is split into smaller chunks and then sent across different machines along with a specific algorithm to manipulate the data (here the user creates his own algorithm, and the worker machines dont know it by default, hence why I want to transfer the function). When the worker machine is done the output is sent back to the first machine which then computes the final result by adding each output together.